# VS2013 C++ Custom Build Tool not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, custom-build-step

My apologies for the lengthy text, but I've been having some trouble using the Custom Build Tool feature in VS2013 for C++ projects.  I want to take a project's "resource.h" file and generate an output file which, for these purposes, we'll call "resource.out".

I wrote a tool that takes two command-line parameters - the "resource.h" file, and the "resource.out" file.  I first tried this on a simple app-wizard-generated doc/view application MFCApplication1.  I added file "resource.x" as a dummy file to get "compiled" using the custom build tool.  On that specific file, I set the "Item Type" to "Custom Build Tool", and when configuring the tool I have the following:

```
Command Line: "<path-to-tool>" resource.h .\res\resource.out
Outputs: .\res\resource.out
Additional Dependencies: resource.h
```

This works.  When I build MFCApplication1, I see the following in my output window:

```
1>  Performing Custom Build Tools
1>  Successfully generated resource out file ('res\resource.out')
```

The second line is output from my custom build tool.  So in this simple test, everything works as I'd expect.

Now I'm trying the same thing on my real code.  I have a solution with a number of projects, and one project is reponsible for taking another project's resources and generating a dll.  The directory structure looks like:

```
Main
    MainApp
        resource.h
    MainRes
        MainRes.vcxproj references "..\MainApp\resource.h"
```

So the MainRes project references the resource file from the MainApp project.  Following what was successful in my MFCApplication1 experiment, I added "resource.x" to the main app, and reference it in MainRes:

```
Main
    MainApp
        resource.h
        resource.x
    MainRes
        MainRes.vcxproj references "..\MainApp\resource.h"
        MainRes.vcxproj references "..\MainApp\resource.x"
```

In the MainRes project, I selected "resource.x" and via the context properties, set its "Item Type" to "Custom Build Tool", and configured it as:

```
Command Line: "<path-to-tool>" ..\MainApp\resource.h ..\MainApp\res\resource.out
Outputs: ..\MainApp\res\resource.out
Additional Dependencies: ..\MainApp\resource.h
```

Now when I attempt to compile "resource.x" in MainRes, I get the following warning (warning MSB8018: No outputs specified for item "..\MainApp\resource.x"):

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): warning MSB8018: No outputs specified for item "..\MainApp\resource.x". Its custom build command will be skipped.
```

So I thought maybe it's a context thing and changed the configuration to:

```
Command Line: "<path-to-tool>" resource.h .\res\resource.out
Outputs: .\res\resource.out
Additional Dependencies: resource.h
```

I get the same warning.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.  I have the 'Outputs' set to a file, and I have the output file in the command line.  Thanks in advance for anyone's help on this one.  I've spent way too much time on it already...

- Steve

Answer (score 1):

Soooo... I finally figured out that for some reason, modifying the Custom Build Tool configuration using the editor was actually saving the data into the vcxproj under the wrong Configuration.  Even though I had the Configuration and Platform set correctly in the editor, it was writing to a different configuration in the file.  Who the hell knows why that is, but lesson learned - always check your vcxproj file!